# Right Hand Limit involving fractional part

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

> The value of $$L=\lim _{x \rightarrow[a]^{+}} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\{x\}}-\{\mathrm{x}\}-1}{\{\mathrm{x}\}^{2}}$$ can be:
> (A) $[a]$
> (B) $2$ 
> (C) $\{a\}$
> (D)$\frac12$
> where where [.]
> and {⋅}
> denotes greatest integer and
> fractional part function respectively

The given answer is (C) and (D).

For $h\to0^+, \{[a]+h\}=h$ :

So limit can be written as $$\lim _{h\to0^+} \frac{\mathrm{e}^h-h-1}{h^2}$$
which gives $L=\dfrac12$

But I have been unable to figure out how to get (C).

Comment: How can two different answers be the answer? Also, you mean $h\to 0^+$?

Comment: It's a multi-correct question "The value of L **can be**". and yes.

Comment: Trivially, it could be $\{a\}$ in the special case $\{a\}=1/2$. So it is technically a correct choice.

Comment: I fail at MCQ. ….